# Set environment variables in Junit5 for each test

Tags: java, junit

I have to migrate tests from JUnit 4 to JUnit 5, I had @Rule which sets EnvironmentVariables variable. In Junit 4 variables  were cleared for each test, in JUnit 5 i need the same behaviour, because now running tests are passing separately, but when I ran all tests from class then the second test fails because still has the same environment variables.

I had:

```
@Rule
 public final EnvironmentVariables environmentVariables = new EnvironmentVariables();

@Test
void method1(){...}


@Test
void method2(){...}
```

I'm not familiar yet with Junit 5 so thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

What you did with `@Rule` in JUnit 4 should be done with [`Extension`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions) that provides a very close feature in JUnit 5.
So you could create an Extension for example `EnvironmentVariablesExtension` that performed the logic of your `@Rule` and use it in your unit test by annotating your test class(es) `@ExtendWith(EnvironmentVariablesExtension.class)`.

Note that if you use a single `@Rule` in a single unit test class, you could move this logic into the `@BeforeEach` lifecyle method that is invoked before each ran test.
If you have just few classes that uses this `setup` in a single project, you can still introduce an abstract base test class that does this setup in a `@BeforeEach` method and make your unit test classes  inherit from this base class.
One of the greatest value of `@Rule` is when you want to define multiple rules for an unit test or as you want to reuse rules in other apps/projects.  It it is not the case, don't feel constraint to introduce them as `Extension` in JUnit5 and keep things simple for the moment.

Comment: The problem is that EnvironmentVariables is tied to JUnit 4 implementing soif you use it in a Extension or BeforeEaech, the apply method is never executed.

Answer (score 1):

The `EnvironmentVariables` rule above looks like System Rules - https://github.com/stefanbirkner/system-rules

This was superseded by System Lambda - https://github.com/stefanbirkner/system-lambda which allows a variable to be set inside the body of a test:

```java
withEnvironmentVariable("FOO", "bar")
   .execute(() -> { ... test code } );
```

However, there is a new library called System Stubs - https://github.com/webcompere/system-stubs which contains the equivalent of the OP's code:

```java
@ExtendWith(SystemStubsExtension.class)
class SomeTest {
   @SystemStub
   private EnvironmentVariables environmentVariables;


   @Test
   void someTest() {
      environmentVariables.set("FOO", "bar");

      // use environment

      // environment cleared at end
   }

}
```

The environment variables object can also be initialised in the `@BeforeEach` method or constructed explicitly to have values in the initializer list of the test class.

Answer (score -3):

I think You have the problem with keyword `final`. Remove it, and it should work,

try like this:

```
@Rule
public EnvironmentVariables environmentVariables = new EnvironmentVariables();
```

> final = define an entity that can only be assigned once

so from my perspective this is messing Your run.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help, i checked that and in second test i still saw variables set for first test